# VS Code Snippet w/ placeholder transform and tab stop

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I would like to have a snippet with two tab stops.  The first tab stop should allow the user to enter text.  The second tab stop should default to a placeholder that is a transform of the text from the first tab stop.  BUT, the second tab stop's transformed value should be selected (i.e. highlighted) so the user can easily override it w/ a custom value.

Here is an example snippet that ALMOST works:

```json
"Test Case": {
  "prefix": "tc",
  "body": [
    "TS1: $1",
    "TS2: ${2:${1/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}}",
    "$0"
  ],
  "description": "Test case to demonstrate issue"
}
```

When you tab after you enter a value in TS1, the cursor goes to the *end* of the transformed TS2 value -- but I want it to act like other placeholders and have the whole value selected already (instead of a cursor at the end).

[image]

Interestingly enough, if I put a space after `${2:` in the snippet, then it *does* select the whole value (like I want) but unfortunately it includes the extra space I inserted to make that happen (which I do not want).

[image]

Is there some trick I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is that it is fixed in the current Insiders Build v1.52 !  I wonder if it was fixed as a side benefit of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/108964?

[image: snippet space bug fixed in Insiders' Build demo]

---

[Before I checked the Insiders' Build]:

I've seen this exact situation before and always meant to file an issue but unfortunately never did.  It is definitely a bug.  Sometimes you can work around it depending on what you actually are wanting to do in the snippet.

In your case, you want to select the transformed version.  But you can "reverse" the transforms and select the non-transformed version ala:

```
// "TS1: $1",
// "TS2: ${2:${1/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}}",    // your code
// "$0"

"TS1: ${1/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}",
"TS2: ${2:$1}",
"$0"
```

You see I am now selecting the non-transformed version and `upcase`ing the first instead of `downcase`ing the second.  And the selection will work.

It all depends on your specific case whether this "workaround" can be used - you might be doing something more complicated than a simple upcase <-> downcase swap would fix based on your actual input.  You could call this snippet in a macro that deletes that unwanted space but that would have to be triggered by a keybinding rather than a snippet prefix so is suboptimal.  Or a second snippet that acts on the now-selected word and preceding space.

Comment: Thanks, Mark!  It's good to know that (a) I'm not alone w/ this type of problem, and (b) that it seems to be fixed in an upcoming version!  Unfortunately, my real use case is more complicated than upcase/downcase, so the alternate approach won't work.  Still, I'm content to wait for that bug fix to make it into an official release!